# EF Core add-migration doesn't work - Could not find assembly x64 instead of x86

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I want to build x86 ASP.NET Core using .Net Framework 4.5.2 on x64 machine. So I install SDK x86.
When I run migration command `add-migration Init` in PMC it throws:

```
Could not find assembly '...\.\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\MisapayHub.exe'.
```

Although compiled assembly placed in

```
....\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x86\MisapayHub.exe'
```

If I install x64 SDK it works, however it can't run on x86 machine.

So my questions:

- In this situation, how to fix it ? I tried with `dotnet ef migrations add Init` but have unsuccessful.
- On x64 machine with x64 SDK, how to compile to x86, or Any CPU?

Environment:

```
- Windows 10 x64.
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
- DotNet Core 1.1.0 x86
```

Project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    // others....
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",        
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  },

  "tools": {
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "platform": "anycpu",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x86": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  },

  // others...
}
```

Comment: Did you solve a problem?

Comment: No, many different errors occur when i fix this one, one by one. I solved it by creating a new project with new db migrations and copypasta to existing project. Hope it'll work properly on next ef version.

Answer (score 0):

So the folder which is created in the local machine contains a folder with "**win7-x87**" as below

"....\bin\Debug\net452**win7-x86**\MisapayHub.exe'"

And the error you get is you cannot find assemble in a folder known as "**win7-x64**" as below

Could not find assembly '....\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\MisapayHub.exe'.

The simplest solution is to navigate to the net452 folder and rename "**win7-x86**" to "**win7-x64**" which will solve the issue.